# How to stay on previous page after signin in codeigniter framework

Tags: codeigniter, frameworks

Hii guys i'm new in stackoverflow , if this question is very long please pardon me, This is a Consumer complain website here is a view page called separate_user_admin_reply2.php in this page i want to apply a functionality, If a user without login click on the replay button then Signin.php view page will appear then after login the user come back to the previous page, the previous page link is : http://localhost/A2Zcomplainboard/index.php/Complain/Separate_single_complain_user/COMP008

So what i can do ..please help me (thanks in advance)

The controller is :

```
public function Separate_single_complain_user($cid)
    {
        //$cid = $this->input->get('compid');
        $this->load->model('Complain_model');
        $res = $this->Complain_model->getSingleComplain($cid);
        $this->load->model('Replay_Model');
        $res1 = $this->Replay_Model->Separate_single_complain_replay($cid);
        if($res){
            $this->load->view('separate_user_admin_reply2',['res'=>$res,'res1'=>$res1]);
        }
    }
```

The model is:

```
public function getSingleComplain($cid)
    {
        $complain = $this->db->query("SELECT comp_id,comp_title,comp_description,post_datetime,status,publish_status,comp_catagory,posted_by,id,first_name,email FROM log_tbl l INNER JOIN comp_tbl c ON l.id = c.posted_by WHERE comp_id = '$cid'");
        $res = $complain->result_array();
        if($res)
                return $res;
        else
            return false;   
    }

public function Separate_single_complain_replay($cid){

        $rep = $this->db->query("SELECT first_name,rep_id,rep_description,rep_datetime,rep_by,rep_against,rep_flag,rating FROM log_tbl l INNER JOIN reply_tbl r ON l.id = r.rep_by WHERE r.rep_against = '$cid 'AND rep_flag = '1'");
        $res = $rep->result_array();
        if($res)
                return $res;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

enter image description here
This is the view page image
separate_user_admin_reply2.php

And the signin controller is :

```
public function index()
    {

            $email = $this->input->post('email');
            $password = $this->input->post('password');
            $this->load->model('Login_Model');
            $data = $this->Login_Model->isvalidate($email,$password);
            
            if($data)
            {
                $this->load->library('session');
                $this->session->set_userdata('email',$data['email']);
                $this->session->set_userdata('type',$data['type']);
                $this->session->set_userdata('id',$data['id']);
                if($data['type']=='User' ){
                    return redirect('User/index');
                }
                else
                 {
                    return redirect('Admin/adminDashboard');
                }
            }else{
                echo "<script>alert('Details not matched')</script>";
                header("refresh:1");
                return redirect('Complain/login');
            }
    }

model:-
public function isvalidate($email,$password)
{

        $q = $this->db->where(['email'=>$email,'password'=>$password])
                      ->get('log_tbl');
                       if($q->num_rows()){
                        $x = $q->row()->email;
                        $y = $q->row()->type;
                        $z = $q->row()->id;
                        
                        $userData = array('email' => $x, 'type' => $y, 'id' => $z);
                        
                        
                        return $userData;
                        
                      }else{
                        return false;
                      }
    }
```

signin view page image:

[image: Signin View Page Image]

Answer (score 0):

Store the previous page url in session data. You can find a detailed description of how to do that in the codeigniter documentation. When the user successfully logged in, check if the previous page data is set, if so flush it and redirect to it.